# How to assign dynamic id to button in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created html table and getting dynamic data in table. But on each button I am calling function, My server side should understand this button. so I need to set dynamic id or name to button. Below is my code. I want to give unique id to submit button.

```
<table cellspacing='0'> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->

    <!-- Table Header -->

        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Subject</th>  
           <th>Action</th>
   </tr>


    <!-- Table Header -->

    <!-- Table Body -->

        <%for (int i = 0; i < row_count; i++) { %>
    <tr id="h<%=i%>"><td><%=list[0][i]%></td>
        <td><%=list[1][i]%></td>
        <td><%=list[2][i]%></td>
        <td><%=list[3][i]%></td>
        <td><%=list[4][i]%></td>

        <td></td>

        <td><button type="submit" id="Submit"  class="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="button_Click" > Approve</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>


    <!-- Table Body -->

</table>
```

I tried to assign id as below but did't worked.

```
<td><button type="submit" id="Submit<%=i%>"  class="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="button_Click" > Approve</button>
        </td>
```

Comment: You should look into a `Repeater` or `GridView` Control.

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean? Did it throw an error? Produce incorrect output? Reformat your hard drive? You need to be specific or we can't really help very easily...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to : **Dictionnary** collection
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx